# Scrapy grab div with multiple classes?

Tags: python, html, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to grab div's with the class: 'product'. The problem is, some of the div's with class 'product' also have the class 'product-small'. So when I use `xpath('//div[@class='product']')`, it only captures the divs with one class and not multiple. How can I do this with scrapy?

Example:

- Catches: `<div class='product'>`
- Doesn't catch: `<div class='product product-small'>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should consider using a CSS selector for this part of your query.

http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#when-querying-by-class-consider-using-css

```
from scrapy import Selector
sel = Selector(text='<div class="product product-small">I am a product!</div>')
print sel.css('.product').extract()
```

If you need to, you can chain CSS and XPath selectors, as in the example on that page.

Comment: I have seen this doc,but I do not think it's useful,cause the content in div is dynamically-loaded,what can we do in this situation?

Answer (score 10):

This could be also solved with `xpath`. You just needed to use [`contains()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/contains):

```
//div[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' product ')]
```

Though, yes, the `CSS selector` option is more compact and readable.

Comment: your xpath selector would also pick up elements with the `not-a-product` class.

Comment: @barraponto yes, but the input to the current  problem doesn't contain elements with `not-a-product` class. Thanks.

Comment: The selector has been edited to perform exact matching of class names (c.f. http://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.1/topics/selectors.html#when-querying-by-class-consider-using-css)